# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named <modulename> after pip install

Tags: python, virtualenv, setuptools

I do my first steps in python package distributions.
Unfortunately, I have `ModuleNotFoundError` after successful install from pip.

My dirs layout is pretty simple:

```
maindir
   |- setup.py
   |- pysoft
         |- __init__.py
         |- main.py
         |- pylib.py
```

main.py:

```py
import pylib


def main():
    print("main program")
    pylib.libfunc()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

pylib.py:

```py
def libfunc():
    print("lib func")
```

setup.py:

```py
import setuptools


setuptools.setup(
    name='pysoft',
    version='0.0.21',
    author='als',
    author_email='als@gnail.com',
    description='deploy tester',
    py_modules=['pylib'],
    packages=setuptools.find_packages(),
    python_requires='>=3.6',
    entry_points={
        'console_scripts': [
            'pysoft = pysoft.main:main',
        ],
    },
)
```

I do packaging and uploading to *test.pypi.org*:

```sh
python3 setup.py sdist bdist_wheel
python3 -m twine upload --repository-url https://test.pypi.org/legacy/ dist/*
```

I setup and start new `virtualenv` and install my package:

```sh
 python3 -m pip install -i https://test.pypi.org/simple/ pysoft
```

Then I try to run it, but got error:

```sh
pysoft 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/fat/buff/tt/bin/pysoft", line 5, in <module>
    from pysoft.main import main
  File "/home/fat/buff/tt/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pysoft/main.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pylib
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pylib'
```

Could you figure out where I have wrong step?

Comment: did you export the path?

Answer (score 4):

You do `import pylib` as if said `pylib` is a top-level module or package. But it's not — it's a submodule of the package `pysoft`. For the proper import do:

```
from pysoft import pylib
```

`py_modules=['pylib']` in your `setup.py` is ignored because `setuptools` cannot find top-level `pylib.py`. But `packages=setuptools.find_packages()` works and include `pysoft` package into distributions.

Comment: Yes, it works now, thank you. But if I try to run it locally (`python ./main.py`) I got error: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pysoft'`

Comment: You need to adapt `$PYTHONPATH` when running locally. Your `main.py` doesn't know about `pysoft/` directory. The simplest fix is `PYTHONPATH=.. ./main.py`